# Java webstart permission issue

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-io

Im trying to create a webstart application.
It runs now but dosen't read all my settings.

The problem occurs when i'm starting the jnlp file and it tries to read another jars resource using Inputstream.

I've already verified my jars and they are all using the same keystore.

I have a jar called Browser that is trying to read a another jar called Bone.

This is how i read the settings inside of my class BoneModule:

```
InputStream settingsStream = IOUtil.getInputStream("bone.settings");
            InputStream defaultSettintgsStream = IOUtil
                    .getResourceAsStream("/com/mee/bone/bone.settings", BoneModule.class);
            SimpleProperties storage = new SimpleProperties(settingsStream,
                    new SimpleProperties(defaultSettintgsStream, null).getProperties());
            storage.setStoreFilename("bone.settings");
            boneSettings.addStorage(storage);
```

I have set my jnlp file to this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://ip-adress/lib" href="launch.jnlp">
 <information>
    <title>Bildlabbet</title>
    <vendor>mee</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
 </information>
 <security>
 <all-permissions/>
 </security>
 <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" initial-heap-size="32m" max-heap-size="128m" />
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="false"/>
    $dependencies
</resources>
<application-desc
      name="Bildlabbet"
      main-class="com.mee.browser.BildlabbetBrowser"
      width="300"height="300">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

My stacktrace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mee.browser.Browser.initModuleModel(Browser.java:639)
    at com.mee.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:438)
    at com.mee.browser.BildlabbetBrowser$1.run(BildlabbetBrowser.java:92)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "bone.settings" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.exists(Unknown Source)
    at com.mee.io.IOUtil.getInputStream(IOUtil.java:143)
    at com.mee.io.IOUtil.getInputStream(IOUtil.java:123)
    at com.mee.bone.BoneModule.getBoneSettings(BoneModule.java:91)
    at com.mee.bone.BoneModule.<init>(BoneModule.java:68)
    ... 21 more
```

As you can see here i can't read the settings file inside the other jar.
My policy-settings for my client and browser is:

```
grant codebase "file:${jars}" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codebase "file:/var/www/lib/*" {
permisson java.security.AllPermisson;
};

grant codebase"file:/http://ip-adress/lib/*" {
permisson java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codebase "file:/home/ubuntu/bildlabbet/lib/*"{
permission java.security.AllPermission;

grant {
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
};

grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Is it even possible to read like this? As it is now im reading my jar on the local drive since it is what webstart do.

To mention is that im reading the jar from a temp directory. I have already tried to debug the file permission for the temp folders.

Is this fixed if i read the jars resources from the server, instead of locally?

Any suggestions would be nice!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`grant {
   permission java.io.FilePermission "/dir/yourfile", "read, write"
}`